# How to migrate data from MySQL to PostgreSQL schema for multitenancy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, database-migration, multi-tenant

I have many identical Ruby on Rails app that runs on one MySQL database each. Now, I want to use just one Ruby on Rails app and just one PostgreSQL database via multitenancy (using PostgreSQL schema).

The problem is, what's a good way to transfer my data from the MySQL databases to the PostgreSQL schemas? I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: You want one PostgreSQL schema (`create schema...`) per tenant?

Comment: Yes 1 schema per tenant. I'll be using apartment gem.

Comment: [PostgreSQL wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL)